# Initialize an Array with optional elements depending on conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the common way when you want to initialize an Array with optional elements in ruby/rails?

Right now I do

```rb
array = []
array << "1st element"
array << "2nd element" if flag?
array << "3rd element"
```

but It feels very verbose and I am guessing it could be slower than when initialized altogether

I'd like to know if there is something like,

```rb
array = [
  "1st element",
  "2nd element" if flag?,
  "3rd element",
]
#=> ["1st element", "3rd element"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good way of doing it, but here's my suggestion:

```
array = [
  "1st element",
  flag? ? "2nd element" : nil,
  "3rd element"
].compact
```

`.compact` will remove all the `nil` values from your array. This will be problematic if you might have nil values.

Comment: You may wish to use `compact!` to avoid the creation of a temporary array.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't quite do it at initialization you can always [insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-insert) the elements afterwards if you know the index:

```
array = ["1st element", "3rd element"]
array.insert(1, "2nd element") if flag?
```

Or a bit more elegantly:

```
array = ["1st element", "3rd element"].tap { |a| a.insert(1, "2nd element") if flag? }
```

The advantage here being that it does not compact the array in case you actually intend to have nil values.

Answer (score 1):

I would emphasize clarity and generality.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
```

```
def concat_some(*arr)
  arr.reduce([]) { |ar,(a,flag)| flag ? ar.concat(a) : ar }
end
```

```
concat_some([a,true], [b,false], [c,true])
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
concat_some([a,false], [b,true], [c,false])
  #=> [4, 5, 6]
```

or

```
def concat_for_indices(*arr, indices)
  indices.reduce([]) { |a,i| a.concat(arr[i]) }
end
```

```
concat_for_indices(a,b,c,[1,2])
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
concat_for_indices(a,b,c,[2])
  #=> [7, 8, 9] 
concat_for_indices(a,b,c,[])
  #=> [] 
concat_for_indices(a,b,c,[0,1,2])
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or

```
def concat_except_for_indices(*arr, indices)
  ((0..arr.size-1).to_a - indices).reduce([]) { |a,i| a.concat(arr[i]) }
end
```

```
concat_except_for_indices(a,b,c, [0])
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
concat_except_for_indices(a,b,c, [1,2])
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 
concat_except_for_indices(a,b,c, [])
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
concat_except_for_indices(a,b,c, [0,1,2])
  #=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not a good idea, but you can do something like this in ruby/rails:

```rb
flag = true
["1st element", eval("'2nd element' if flag"), "3rd element"].compact 
# output: ["1st element", "2nd element", "3rd element"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the splat operator `*`:

```
array = [
  "1st element",
  *("2nd element" if flag?),
  "3rd element"
]
```

This works because `*"2nd element"` returns the string and `*nil` effectively removes itself:

```
["1st element", *"2nd element", "3rd element"]
#=> ["1st element", "2nd element", "3rd element"]

["1st element", *nil, "3rd element"]
#=> ["1st element", "3rd element"]
```

Note that `*` attempts to call `to_a` so this might have undesired effects if your objects implements that method: (this is [`Time#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Time.html#to_a-method))

```
["1st element", *Time.now, "3rd element"]
#=> ["1st element", 56, 43, 11, 15, 10, 2020, 4, 289, true, "CEST", "3rd element"]
```